# R - Combine multiple random forests contained in a list

Tags: r, list, random-forest

Is there a quick and easy way to pass randomForest objects contained in a list into the combine() function?

As a result of calling `randomForest` through `lapply()`, I now have 10 randomForests in a list (`rfors`).

I want to combine all 10 of them. Understandably `combine(rfors)` doesn't work as it doesn't recognise the individual forests within the list.

I have spend quite sometime messing around with `unlist()`, `lapply()` and `apply()` to try and extract the information in a suitable format but to no avail. The only thing that works is `combine(rfors[[1]], rfors[[2]] ...etc)`.

This is a bit cumbersome though, not least because the number of random forests I'll need to combine is likely to change. Any sleek and elegant solution to this someone can suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the example from `?combine`:

```
data(iris)
rf1 <- randomForest(Species ~ ., iris, ntree=50, norm.votes=FALSE)
rf2 <- randomForest(Species ~ ., iris, ntree=50, norm.votes=FALSE)
rf3 <- randomForest(Species ~ ., iris, ntree=50, norm.votes=FALSE)
rf <- do.call(combine,list(rf1,rf2,rf3))
```

Comment: How does this work if you have 1000 models?